# Is it permissible to use strlcpy to copy an array to itself?

Tags: programming, c

**Task:** delete "\n" at the beginning of the array.

**Example:**

```
char s_msg[15] = "\nHello world!";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Load");
  // Search \n
  if(strstr(s_msg, "\n") != NULL) {
    Serial.println(s_msg);
    strlcpy(s_msg, &s_msg[1], sizeof(s_msg));
    Serial.println(s_msg);
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

**Description:**
If the \ n character is present at the beginning of the message, then we copy the original character to the same character, but without \ n.

**Question:** is it ok to copy char to itself (s_msg is the destination buffer and the source string at the same time)

Comment: why are you asking? ... try it first, then post a question if it does not work as expected

Comment: The documentation of `strlcpy()` should tell you. You might also look into `memmove()` and `memcpy()`.

Comment: this functions are 50 years old. there are books an many Internet sites describing them

Comment: the other question is why do you need to delete the leafing character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [manual page of `strlcpy()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strlcpy&sektion=3) is quite clear:

> If the `src` and `dst` strings overlap, the behavior is undefined.

This means you should avoid it, even if it works on some tests. The
advice you got of just trying is *not* good advice. Use
[`memmove()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=memmove&sektion=3) instead.